# Asynchronous Client & Socket Examples on MSDN to implement Winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, msdn

I am trying to use MSDN examples [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx) to implement winforms.
But I could not figure out where to fit *StartListening* method call. In example, it has been done in main. I tried to call this method on button click event, but it did not worked. If anyone has done with it, please help me out?

Comment: *it did not work* doesn't say much about what is happening? `StartListening` is a blocking method, if you want to call it without blocking the UI thread, you need to call it probably in a new thread.

Comment: and where would i make that new thread?

Comment: i was calling it as normal method i.e.startListening()

Comment: when i used Thread th=new Thread(new Thread(AsynchronousSocketListener.Startlistening)),it's working..thank you

Comment: Glad that it helped, Next time don't just say not working but say what happened instead, Any Exception? Compiler error? etc

Comment: Your code will help more to understand exact problem. The example given in link works perfectly. So, Can you make it more clear? You can you post your code where you call the StartListenng method. Coz, your words **It did not worked** says lot more: for example *Method doesnt get executed, Socket could not get the client request, Cursor goes inside the loop but, nothing happens.* So, try to make it clear what exact problem you are getting now. you can also write description about what you have tried to solve it. ie. placed a break point in while loop, at the beginning and debug it by F11, etc.